# Google Analytics in iOS 8 using Swift don't work

Tags: swift, google-analytics, ios8, xcode6

I have integrated [Google Analytics library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) to my project.

Then I configured the [bridging header file](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) and I've added the following headers Google Analytics

```
#import "Libraries/GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h"
#import "Libraries/GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h"
#import "Libraries/GoogleAnalytics/GAILogger.h"
#import "Libraries/GoogleAnalytics/GAITracker.h"
#import "Libraries/GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

The initialization of the library in the AppDelegate.swift compiles and runs correctly.
I add the following code to track an event

```
var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory(category, action: action, label: label, value: value).build())
```

When trying to generate the build, the following error occurs

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSOverwriteMergePolicy", referenced from:
    -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from:
    -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
    -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
    _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
    _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
    _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
    _kDefaultReachabilityApi in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Xcode 6 GM and try to compile the application running in the iPhone 5s simulator.

**EDIT1:**

Libraries required had already been added

- CoreData.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libz.dylib

I have partially solved the error adding in bridging header file the following imports

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

The error message is reduced to

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_deflate", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
    +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**EDIT2:**

Finally I solved the problem.

In *Target Settings -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags* add the following flag: `-lz`

Comment: I just added Google Analytics for mobile to my Swift app and didn't have to go through quite as many of your hoops. I only had to add GAI.h and <CoreData/CoreData.h> to the bridging-header and it works fine. Didn't have to fiddle with the build settings. They might have added better support since your post.

Answer (score 2):

@Ezequiel Perez : You have to include the targets linked libraries.

> ```
> CoreData.framework
> SystemConfiguration.framework
> libz.dylib
> ```

Try including this....

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all the Objective-C libraries GA needs explicitly.

In the error output you can see that it is looking for Core Data but instead finds "undefined symbols". That shows you that it is missing the library. Notice that the Objective-C libraries are distinct from the modules you import in Swift.

To solve this, go to build phases of your target and link to the necessary libraries, starting with `CoreData.framework`. Consult the GA documentation on which other libraries you need.

EDIT:

I made a quick app, added GA and made it work by adding the libraries. Maybe you could try removing the libs.dylib library and re-adding it. I also recommend to just include the headers by name

```
#include "GAI.h"
```

Comment: Libraries required had already been added.
After reading your answer I have made ​​some changes and updated the question.